# How do I automatically clear data/transfer a range of cells when one cell changes?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a cell, A3, which automatically updates the date weekly. How do I clear one range of cells and transfer other ranges of cells to shift up to stay in line with the correct date when my date (refernce cell) updates?

I'd like to clear the entire new week and shift up the last range up to the top section.

I'm brand new to coding, but I've been toying with onEdit and some clearRange scripts, but only been able to get the function below to work.

```
function onEdit(e) {
      // replace 'Sheet1' with your actual sheet name
      // replace 'dhrhrejYOURSHETIDerhe5j54j5j' with your actual sheet ID

      var sheetActive = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1YiW7zuZWptQcin5l1DkJfjxPC1xGN6_mGWLWfFDFcy4").getSheetByName("Sheet1");
      sheetActive.getRange('B4:E8').clearContent();

    }
```

My spreadsheet is here:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YiW7zuZWptQcin5l1DkJfjxPC1xGN6_mGWLWfFDFcy4/edit#gid=0

Comment: `How do I clear one range of cells and transfer other ranges of cells to shift up to stay in line with the correct date when my date (refernce cell) updates?` Would you please explain this.

Comment: BTW, you spreadsheet requires access request.